# UEFI boot menu items for Ubuntu and Linux Mint both launch Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, grub-efi, mint

I tried installing Ubuntu 16.04 and Linux Mint 18 on separate partitions of a hard drive, with two other partitions to be mounted as `/boot` (one for each).  The idea was to have the two systems completely independent and to select between them through the laptop's UEFI boot menu.  I was also hoping to be able to make each boot loader see the other one.  In the future I planned to add yet another distribution.

The first thing that seems to be out of order is that the installers of both Ubuntu and Mint asked me where to install the boot loaders, despite that Ubuntu's community documentation [says](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Performing_the_Installation):

> Note that in a UEFI-mode installation, Ubuntu will not ask you where to install the boot loader. If it does, or if it complains about the lack of a BIOS Boot Partition, you've probably accidentally booted in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode.

(I am pretty sure that I was booted in UEFI-mode: "Launch CSM" was disabled in UEFI setup, and at the end the installed systems were mounting EFI system partition under `/boot/efi`.)

As I had to choose where to install the boot loaders, I selected them to be installed to respective `/boot` partitions.

After installing Ubuntu, it showed up in UEFI boot menu.  Inspecting the ESP (EFI system partition), I found that a directory `/EFI/ubuntu` was created.  With help of `efibootmgr`, I determined that the startup file for Ubuntu was `\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI`.  (In fact, the first time I tried installing Ubuntu, I selected "do not use this partition" for ESP, but it was used nonetheless.)

Afterwards I installed Mint, and what happened was that "ubuntu" item in UEFI boot menu started launching Mint's GRUB instead of Ubuntu's GRUB, and I found no way to start Ubuntu anymore.  It turned out that Mint had overwritten the `/EFI/ubuntu` directory on ESP with its own files.

*My main problem is still ahead.*

I have figured out that if I reinstall Mint's GRUB with the following command

```
sudo grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --bootloader-id=linux-mint
```

it will create a `EFI/linux-mint` directory with its startup "kernels."  Here is the contents of this directory after the above operation:

```
$ sudo ls -l /boot/efi/EFI/linux-mint
total 3546
-rwx------ 1 root root     121 juil. 28 22:05 grub.cfg
-rwx------ 1 root root 1067896 juil. 28 22:05 grubx64.efi
-rwx------ 1 root root 1271672 juil. 28 22:05 MokManager.efi
-rwx------ 1 root root 1289424 juil. 28 22:05 shimx64.efi
```

Through UEFI setup, I added "linux-mint" boot option pointing to `/EFI/linux-mint/shimx64.efi`, and it worked.
(I regret now not having removed `/EFI/ubuntu` directory first for a cleaner experiment).

I reinstalled Ubuntu, and it recreated its `/EFI/ubuntu`:

```
$ sudo ls -l /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu
total 3610
drwx------ 2 root root    1024 juil. 28 22:23 fw
-rwx------ 1 root root   64352 juil. 28 22:23 fwupx64.efi
-rwx------ 1 root root     121 juil. 28 22:25 grub.cfg
-rwx------ 1 root root 1067896 juil. 28 22:25 grubx64.efi
-rwx------ 1 root root 1271672 juil. 28 22:25 MokManager.efi
-rwx------ 1 root root 1289424 juil. 28 22:25 shimx64.efi
```

In UEFI boot menu, "ubuntu" entry appeared automatically together with the "manually" created before "linux-mint".  The "ubuntu" entry launched Ubuntu's GRUB, as expected.  I inspected the UEFI boot menu with `efibootmgr -v` and checked that "ubuntu" was pointing to `\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI` and "linux-mint" was pointing to `\EFI\LINUX-MINT\SHIMX64.EFI`:

```
$ sudo efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,0003,0000,0005
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,e430ad60-82d4-4bbf-93df-dc0690541c64,0x800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...1................
Boot0001* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,e430ad60-82d4-4bbf-93df-dc0690541c64,0x800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI)
Boot0003* linux-mint    HD(1,GPT,e430ad60-82d4-4bbf-93df-dc0690541c64,0x800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\LINUX-MINT\SHIMX64.EFI)
Boot0005* Hard Drive    BBS(HD,,0x0)..GO..NO........o.H.G.S.T. .H.T.S.5.4.1.0.1.0.A.7.E.6.3.0....................A...........................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L. . . . . . .0.S.0.0.1.0.S.S.T.H.3.1.F.Y........BO..NO........o.H.F.S.1.2.8.G.3.9.M.N.C.-.2.3.0.0.A....................A...........................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.I.E.9.5.0.N.7.5.1.2.7.0.9.0.5.I. .P. . ........BO
```

I selected "linux-mint" from UEFI boot menu, and it launched Ubuntu's GRUB.  Please help me.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the output of `sudo efibootmgr -v` on your system.

Comment: Does Ubuntu grub have Mint in menu? Grub in Ubuntu and Mint is same.

Comment: No.  No matter which i install first, the second does not see it.  But this bothers me less than that the first is no longer bootable from UEFI boot menu.

Comment: I would think Mint would change grub to not use /EFI/ubuntu. I have multiple installs of Ubuntu in UEFI mode. Only difference when it overwrites my /EFI/ubuntu is actually the /EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg. That only is three lines that is a configfile to the full grub.cfg in your install. But I also tried renaming my various Ubuntu installs and creating separate UEFI folders and entires. But found grub is hard coded to find /EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg.  Have not found where that is in grub. Not considered important: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1450783

Comment: @oldfred, thanks for the idea.  If grub is hardcoded to look for `/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg`, this may explain the behavior.  I really made a mistake in my experiment by not removing `/EFI/ubuntu` before trying to start Mint through `/EFI/linux-mint`.

Comment: @oldfred, you are right, it is all because of the hardcoded `/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg`.  If I put `grub.cfg` from Mint to `/EFI/ubuntu`, i get Mint's boot menu in GRUB.  I wonder now how to have both...

Comment: I have seen Boot-Repair reports with other Linux. And they have there own folders. So other distributions do modify grub2. But I have not installed any of them yet, and then tried to compare grub to see where difference is.

Answer (score -1):

First boot to your Ubuntu live CD and:

Install Ubuntu, and when you reach the partitioning area:

1. Make a partition for Ubuntu root (`/`) and:
2. Make a partition for boot (`/boot`) MAKE SURE IT'S FORMATTED AS FAT32 and:
3. Set "install boot-loader to" the partition you made for boot (`/boot`) and:
4. Finish the installation and boot to your UEFI settings. by pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>DEL</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd> or some other key depending on you computer manufacturer and:
5. Add an entry for Ubuntu. Navigate to Ubuntu's boot partition then select `grubx64.efi` file.
6. Select that entry every time you boot up to use Ubuntu
7. Do the same for Linux Mint